# Python CRC calculation for the NTAG 424 NFC chip

Tags: nfc, crc

I am currently working with the [NXP NTAG 424 chips](https://www.nxp.com/products/rfid-nfc/nfc-hf/ntag/ntag-for-tags-labels/ntag-424-dna-424-dna-tagtamper-advanced-security-and-privacy-for-trusted-iot-applications:NTAG424DNA), which feature AES-128 encryption.

This chip requires the computation of a crc32 checkvalue whenever a new key is set (see the [datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/NT4H2421Gx.pdf) 11.6.1/Page 67). According to the data sheet, the crc is "computed according to IEEE Std802.3-2008". The [application note](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN12196.pdf) (6.16.1/page 39) even gives an example for this :

```
new_key: F3847D627727ED3BC9C4CC050489B966
CRC32(new_key): 789DFADC
```

However when I try to replicate the results using python and the binascii crc32 library, the result is different:

```
>>> from binascii import unhexlify, crc32
>>> new_key = unhexlify('F3847D627727ED3BC9C4CC050489B966')
>>> print(hex(crc32(new_key)))
0x23056287     # Not the CRC I was looking for
```

This document often reverses byte order, however the command

```
>>> print(hex(crc32(new_key[::-1])))
0x9453faa7
```

also brings no joy.

So the question is: What am I doing wrong? I tried consulting the cited standard, but with my superficial knowledge I could not spot any difference between the standard crc32 and the algorithm cited in the IEEE standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The example's CRC is the ***COMPLEMENT*** of the 32-bit CRC that IEEE Std802.3 (or equivalently CCITT V.42) specifies, which I detail [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/3375/555) with reference. This is another case of using a variant of a standard CRC in this tag: like all ISO/IEC 14443 type A tags, its error detection (up to 848 kbit/s) uses a variant of the 16-bit CRC that IEEE Std802.3 (or equivalently CCITT V.42) specifies, with different initial value and lacking the final complement.

Here is self-contained code that matches the question's test vector:

```
# compute the CRC32 for NTAG424
# Ethernet / CCITT V42 CRC32, less final complement
def NTAG424CRC(m):
    c = 0xFFFFFFFF
    for b in m:
         c ^= b;
         for n in range(8):
             c = (c>>1)^(0xEDB88320&-(c&1))
#   c ^= 0xFFFFFFFF  # required by Ethernet / CCITT V42
    return c.to_bytes(4,'little')

# demo, expected value 789dfadc
print(NTAG424CRC(bytearray.fromhex('F3847D627727ED3BC9C4CC050489B966')).hex())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZBNa4NAEIbv/oqBQNyF1BrdRm1JoNl80EsPJfSYoutYBV3tZi36662ahOTQOc4887zMVK1OS@l23QREWVS1RtApAv/grgNJqeD98LpnDjMmsO0HSqKGR@D87XCAT@acwRnkeDpBkskwHzU5Fii1EWNy3e85UtBnA/oSsAS72V1qbA1JEWQSijMCZ@64hOjl1hgoOVAqlN9IfHoHX8VErFZzeiR2s92sfd917OkDEdM5pf0JF@ctHGACCn/qTGEMUfvvjWOGQl0rCcLS5VfUajwRNjPzTOscTWr06hiLcgbYVCh07/oN8xrB84M4CWNhVCqTmtz9YnCESoWtlaiySLEh5s71mbdZOJ7neNuNu@YBZ5zbTzbzg3WwWJiUWgNIadf9AQ)

> What am I doing wrong?

- Trusting that the manufacturer faithfully implemented its own specification.
- Expecting the output of `binascii.crc32` to be big-endian; it's little-endian, and must be so in telecom to preserve the burst-error detection property of CRC32. It is an oversight in the specification of `binascii.crc32` to have an `int` as output, when using a `bytearray` like its input would make endianess error next to impossible.

We can and probably should use `binascii.crc32`, which is native and uses a pre-computed table, thus is much faster (but may be more susceptible to cache-related side-channel attacks).

```
import binascii

# compute the CRC32 for NTAG424 using binascii.crc32
# Ethernet / CCITT V42 CRC32, less final complement
def NTAG424CRC(m):
    return (binascii.crc32(m)&0xFFFFFFFF^0xFFFFFFFF).to_bytes(4,'little')
# &0xFFFFFFFF deals with negative output; it can be removed under Python 3
# ^0xFFFFFFFF undoes the complement rightly done by binascii.crc32

# demo, expected value 789dfadc
print(NTAG424CRC(bytearray.fromhex('F3847D627727ED3BC9C4CC050489B966')).hex())
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBNT4NAEL3zKyYxEUgabABL0ZPdtsaLMU3jUbOwQ9lk2SXLUMuvx239aHVOk8z7mPfagWqjk3GUTWssQSE170opPe8KStO0PSFQjcA2LImhMhaetw@PaZxC30m9@8VHpS2T2JFWDm01EtwAY0/bLbym8Rd7Agq7DirHUCdthQ1q8gRWP6IOFzThnQduLFJvNQR/Hdz5enpYf8/beQ0jMu/FQNgF6cRXkkihH7qHLuAgkKsOPiTVoHHHSe4RTE8u5T1IgpJrKNA5N2aPAnot0MLLqSFInNSF3fFosDt1c84CVu5qUgMIoxGK4X89TkM48QngocWSnMeeqx4hm@ei4qL0Wis1BRdtHBNxa/kQVdY0NR4Cf53M02w5i7MszlbLZMFyljI2vZ2m83yRz2Z@GEZHYBiO4yc)

Comment: I just tried it with the NTAG 424, it works as expected, but only if the authentication happens directly before you try to change the key (at least for me, that may or may not be either an issue with my command counter increment (although it works good for all my other commands) or another undocumented "feature" of the NTAG 424). 
But thanks for the solution including the binascii.crc32 call, that one works beautifully!

Comment: "What am I doing wrong? Trusting that the manufacturer faithfully implemented its own specification." - I had a good laugh=) quite true. also, great answer, thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
function NTAG424CRC(m) {
  let c = 4294967295; // 0xffffffff
  for (let i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
    c = c ^ m[i];
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      c = (c >>> 1) ^ (3988292384 & -(c & 1));   // 3988292384 === 0xEDB88320
    }
  }

  let buffer = new ArrayBuffer (4);     // 4 === length of crc32 in decimal
  let view = new DataView(buffer);
  view.setUint32(0, c, true);
  let bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
  return bytes;
}

let crc32Value = NTAG424CRC(
  new Uint8Array([
    0xf3, 0x84, 0x7d, 0x62, 0x77, 0x27, 0xed, 0x3b, 0xc9, 0xc4, 0xcc, 0x05,
    0x04, 0x89, 0xb9, 0x66,
  ])
);

console.log(Buffer.from(crc32Value).toString("hex").toUpperCase()); //789DFADC
//javascript CRC32 calculation for ntag 424 DNA
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).